# call a JAX WS webservice from the server without http or servlets

Tags: jax-ws, playframework

I've created a SOAP based JAX-WS server (classes and WSDL created with
wsgen).  I've successfully tested this by creating a stand-alone
server with Endpoint.publish() and connected to it successfully with
java, perl and .NET clients. Now I would like to deploy it on a
non-servlet based web framework (Play Framework).

Unfortunately even
after looking all over the web for docs and code I can't figure out
how to invoke the webservice outside of http from within the server.
On the play side, the framework routes an http POST request to a
static java method.  It's easy to access the soap packet but I can't
figure out how to pass it to JAX WS for invokation.

In a nuteshell here's what I'm trying to do

```
public class Application extends Controller 
{
    // function referenced by routing table
    public static void func1() {
        // TODO: use play to get SOAP request from caller
        String soapRequest = playFrameworkCode();

        Object implementor = MyJaxWsWebService();

        // !!! insert JAX WS code here !!!
        Object magicJaxWsObject;
        String soapResult = magicJaxWsObject.invoke(soapRequest);

        // TODO: use Play to return SOAP result to caller
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bunch of trial and error I have a solution.  Below is the non-servlet invoker class as well as an example of calling it.

My biggest concern is that my solution has a lot of references to com.sun.xml.ws.*  Am I shooting myself in the foot for doing this?  Are there any JAX WS developers reading this that can give me a thumbs up or thumbs down on this solution?

```
package controllers.ws;

import com.sun.xml.ws.api.BindingID;
import com.sun.xml.ws.api.WSBinding;
import com.sun.xml.ws.api.message.Packet;
import com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.InstanceResolver;
import com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.Invoker;
import com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.SDDocumentSource;
import com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint;
import com.sun.xml.ws.binding.BindingImpl;
import com.sun.xml.ws.message.saaj.SAAJMessage;
import com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory;
import com.sun.xml.ws.transport.Headers;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.MimeHeader;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPException;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPPart;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext;

/**
 * This is the glue between a non-servlet based web server and the JAX
 * WS server functionality.  Given a web service definition (WSDL
 * file, generated classes) offer a function that takes unmarshalled
 * soap, runs the service, and returns the soap response.
 *
 * This currently does not run on jax-ws 2.0.x (the version installed
 * in most jdk6 installs) but it does work with a custom download of
 * jax-ws.  You must do the following to get this working:
 *
 * 
 *
 * download the zipfile from http://jax-ws.java.net/ This class
 * has been tested to work with v2.2.3
 *
 * add the two jars jaxb-api.jar and jaxws-api.jar to the
 * jdk/jre/lib/endorsed directory
 *
 * place all jars except the above two into the classpath
 *
 * 
 *
 * Note: this code is only used on the server side so it is something
 * we should always have a lot of control over.  The client can still
 * connect with any version of jax ws or any soap/wsdl framework.
 *
 * TODO: it's not clear how stable this code is.  Writing it required
 * examining the source of the entire jax ws framework and performing
 * lots of trial and error.  We should really check with the jax ws
 * guys for guidance.
 */
public class ServiceInvoker {

    private ExecutorService executorService;
    private WSEndpoint endpoint;
    private Class clazz;

    public ServiceInvoker(Class clazz) {
        // interweb wisdom says that generic class info is compile
        // time only so the only way to get the class of T
        // (e.g. T.getClass()) is to have an instance of T or
        // explicitly pass the class in like this.
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    /**
     * Starts the service including creating an executor to run the commands
     *
     * @param service the QName of the service as specified in the WSDL
     * @param port the QName of the port as specified in the WSDL
     * @param wsdlFname the actual WSDL file assumed to be in the root
     * of the class dir
     */
    public void start(QName service, QName port, URL wsdlUrl) {
        Invoker invoker = InstanceResolver.createDefault(clazz).createInvoker();
        WSBinding binding = BindingImpl.create(BindingID.parse(clazz));
        SDDocumentSource doc = SDDocumentSource.create(wsdlUrl);

        endpoint = 
            EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(
                                           clazz, // Class implType, 
                                           true, // boolean processHandlerAnnotation, 
                                           invoker, // @Nullable Invoker invoker,
                                           service, // @Nullable QName serviceName, 
                                           port, // @Nullable QName portName,
                                           null, // @Nullable Container container, 
                                           binding, // @Nullable WSBinding binding,
                                           doc, // @Nullable SDDocumentSource primaryWsdl,
                                           null, //@Nullable Collection metadata,
                                           null, // EntityResolver resolver,
                                           true // boolean isTransportSynchronous
                                           );

        executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        endpoint.setExecutor(executorService);
    }

    /**
     * Cleans up the invoker by shutting down any remaining threads.
     * The JVM may not terminate if this function is not called.
     */
    public void stop() {
        if (executorService != null) {
            executorService.shutdown();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Given a WSDL compliant soap request for the service, runs the
     * service, and returns a WSDL compliant SOAP response/fault.
     */
    public String invoke(String soapText) {

        SOAPMessage sm = stringToSoap(soapText);
        Packet packet = createPacket(sm);

        MyOnCompletion c = new MyOnCompletion();
        endpoint.schedule(packet,c);
        return c.waitForResult();
    }

    private static SOAPMessage stringToSoap(String soapText) {
        SOAPMessage message;
        try {
            // Create SoapMessage
            MessageFactory msgFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
            message = msgFactory.createMessage();
            SOAPPart soapPart = message.getSOAPPart();

            // Load the SOAP text into a stream source
            byte[] buffer = soapText.getBytes();
            ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer);
            StreamSource source = new StreamSource(stream);

            // Set contents of message
            soapPart.setContent(source);

            return message;
        } catch (SOAPException  e) {
            // TODO: what do we return when we can't parse the
            // incoming soap?
            System.out.println("SOAPException : " + e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static Packet createPacket(SOAPMessage arg) {
        Iterator iter = arg.getMimeHeaders().getAllHeaders();
        Headers ch = new Headers();
        while(iter.hasNext()) {
            MimeHeader mh = (MimeHeader) iter.next();
            ch.add(mh.getName(), mh.getValue());
        }
        Packet packet = new Packet(new SAAJMessage(arg));
        packet.invocationProperties.put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, ch);
        return packet;
    }

    /**
     * The JAX WS invoker framework is designed for asynchronous
     * calls.  We want to treat the calls synchronously so this class
     * allows us to easily wait for the invoked call to complete and
     * return the value to the caller.
     */
    private static class MyOnCompletion implements WSEndpoint.CompletionCallback {
        private Object mutex;
        private String result;
        public MyOnCompletion() {
            // we could use the MyOnCompletion class as a mutex but
            // this is safer (no one else can send notify messages)
            mutex = new Object();
        }
        public void onCompletion(Packet response) {
            try {
                SOAPMessage sm = response.getMessage().readAsSOAPMessage();
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                sm.writeTo(out);
                synchronized(mutex) {
                    result = out.toString();
                    mutex.notify();
                }
            } catch (SOAPException e) {
                // we should never expect the JAX WS framework to
                // return invalid SOAP
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // we should never expect the JAX WS framework to
                // return invalid SOAP
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        public String waitForResult() {
            synchronized(mutex) {
                if (result != null) {
                    return result;
                }
                try {
                    mutex.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the caller...

```
public class Application extends Controller 
{
   /**
     * The entrypoint to a webservice call
     *
     * Strangely the argument "String body" hs to be named "body" as
     * it triggers Play! to pass the raw html POST info.
     */
    public static void fibonacci(String body) {

        // TODO: it would probably be good to cache this and reuse it
        // over many calls. (not sure how expensive this is)
        ServiceInvoker invoker;
        {
            invoker = new ServiceInvoker(Fibonacci.class);

            QName service = 
                new QName(
                          "http://scharp.org/fib/", 
                          "FibonacciService");
            QName port = 
                new QName(
                          "http://scharp.org/fib/", 
                          "FibonacciPort");

            URL wsdlUrl;
            try {
                wsdlUrl = Play.getFile("lib/FibonacciService.wsdl").toURI().toURL();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

            invoker.start(service, port, wsdlUrl);
        }

        String requestOrFault = invoker.invoke(body);

        invoker.stop();

        renderXml(requestOrFault);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great basic solution! Did you know or suggest how can you introduce automatic WSDL generation and publish (classical request on http://.../ws/test?WSDL )?

Answer (score 1):

I could not help but ask - why are you mixing SOAP with Play? The whole rationale behind Play! is to have a completely RESTful, stateless, share-nothing architecture. Can you elaborate your particular use case that warrants for a design like this?

Comment: That's a good question.  I like SOAP/WSDL for programmatic web interfaces because it provides a contract based interface.  Basically you can write an arbitrarily complex java method which takes complex arguments, returns complex values and throws exceptions and the interface can then be exported as a WSDL doc

Comment: Clients (of all languages and platforms) can use the WSDL doc to generate function stubs that allow them to call the web service and automatically marshall/demarshall their parameters, return values and exceptions. These functions can be stateless.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate Java Web Service Client via wsimport tool to parse the published wsdl file and generate necessary client files (stub) to access the published web service.
Because of wsimport tool is bundle with the JDK and you can find it at “JDK_PATH/bin” folder, you do not need import any library in your project.

```
wsimport -keep http://domain-name/ws/ws-name?wsdl
```

A class that annotate using @WebServiceClient (e.g. Pgw_Service in my case) is your web service client class and you can use it to call your web service:

```
    Pgw_Service service = new Pgw_Service();
    System.out.println(service.getPgwPort().test("saeed"));
```